# Workaround for Webkit SVG foreignObject background layering bug?

Tags: webkit, svg

When embedding html inside of SVG using the foreignObject tag, webkit based browsers render the backgrounds of the embedded html elements behind the svg elements.  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35545 .

Here's an example : http://www.mxgraph.com/demo/markup/webkitbg.html
The green div should be on top of the red.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?  Maybe some incantation of z-index and/or grouping of elements or something in svg to fool webkit into doing the right thing?

Comment: Cool.  Your link completely kills Firefox 8 & 9.

Answer (score 3):

This is webkit bug [58417](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58417), fixed on 2011-11-10.  The fix is in Chromium version 17, which is currently in beta as of 2012-01-09, and should be released in early February.  Not sure when the fix will land in Safari, but luckily I don't need to support it.

So the workaround seems to be "wait a month"...

Answer (score 0):

I've just been hit by the same issue. Even though the bug is fixed since a long time in Chrome, Safari seems to be ages behind with the codebase.

My solution is to add `style="display:inline-block"` to the first child of the `foreignObject` tag. This seems to fix the problem.