# Changing the foreignobject stack order

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am currently experimenting with svg in html and have a stack of overlapping `foreignObject` elements. I would like to be able to bring an individual `foreignObject` to the front of the stack using javascript.

I can't seem to get the `zIndex` property to work with them and I'm not sure what else I could try.

Is it possible? How could I do this?

Comment: Did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482115/with-javascript-can-i-change-the-z-index-layer-of-an-svg-g-element ?

Comment: @mguimard thanks for that, the appendChild worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

On an [older post on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434511/workaround-for-webkit-svg-foreignobject-background-layering-bug), a user said:

> My solution is to add style="display:inline-block" to the first child
>   of the foreignObject tag. This seems to fix the problem.